# Rails 3 & assets pipeline in development/production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, production

Precompiling assets on the production server is very slow. So I have decided to recompile them on the development machine and upload assets to the Amazon S3 by `jammit`. Everything's done but I have some negative problems:

1. I have to include `public/assets` directory to `git` control. Because if `public/assets` directory is empty on the production server fails
2. If I precompile assets on the development machine `application.js` includes in the HTML as compressed and that way I have duplicated js code. Changing js doesn't make any effect because precompiled `application.js` interrupts this code.

That way my development process includes following steps:

1. Remove precompiled assets if I'm going to change js or css
2. Do some changes
3. Precompile assets
4. Upload assets to S3 by `jammit-s3`
5. Do commit and push my changes including assets to the git server
6. Deploy by capistrano

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to configure development environment don't include compressed `application.js` if I have it in `public/assets` directory?
2. Is it possible to configure production environment to work with empty `public/assets` directory? Assets will only be on the S3 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by including assets dir in gitignore and exclude only one file - `public/assets/manifest.yml` and production server works correctly now, i.e. `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"` works. It requires only `manifest.yml` file

Answer (score 2):

For question one I don't know a permanent solution other than running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

before you switch back to development mode. I'd be interested to see if you can just ignore the assets in development without turning the entire assets pipeline off.

In production.rb there is an option for your second question:

```
# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"
```

It should then ignore your assets directory since it relies on the remote host.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I have set `config.action_controller.asset_host` if production mode but I have to have precompiled assets in `public/assets` path anyway because server fails without them

Comment: You might want to try some different settings as well then. Could you post your production.rb because it's really hard to tell what you've done and what not.
Try to minimize Rails' use of assets like:
`config.assets.compile = false`
So it won't try to generate them anyway.

Comment: Also, how does the server fail? It doesn't register the remote asset_host and checks the public/assets dir? Is it then actually serving them from the app or the asset_host?

Comment: I turned off `config.assets.compile` but it didn't make any effect. I assets dir is empty server fails with exception message: `Can't find application.css`. But if assets dir is not empty all assets goes from `asset_host` i.e. s3

Comment: I hate to go like, can't you just put some assets there then if that works, because that'll ruin the clean structure you're probably trying to achieve. I did some research, but couldn't find anything else that could cause you having problems with it. Update Rails to the latest version and try to set up a quick test with a new (test) app. If that causes the same thing to happen you might have stumbled upon a bug and you should report it on the github repo under issues. Good luck!